# HighStock navigator from a stacked area chart shows wrong series

Tags: highcharts

I got a little problem in [HighStocks](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock): I have two area series which are stacked. The problem: In the navigator at the bottom, just the first series is shown, not the resulted stacked chart.

(see http://jsfiddle.net/Je8eG/)

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 10), 53.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 10, 30), 59.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 11), 53.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 12), 28.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 13), 55.2]
        ],
        type: 'area'
    }, {
        name: 'Series 2',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 10), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 10, 30), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 11), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 12), 61.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 13), 53.4]
        ],
        type: 'area'
    }]
});
```

Is there a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is not supported. You can set specific series to a navigator, so I advice to sum on your own stacked series, and then pass to navigator, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series

Comment: Well, that's maybe not an answer but at least a quite good workaround. Thx for this answer.

Comment: Well, the answer is in first sentence. You can vote for something like that on [userVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series)