# Highcharts/Highstock navigator won't reflect main chart data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to represent multi-series events on a timeline using a column chart in Highstock.  For some reason the navigator won't show the data from all series in the main chart.  It appears to be tied to a single series, but I can't find anything in the [API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) that would make it show all the data.

[image]

jsFiddle: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/whiletrue/s6BmC/9/)

Highcharts.stockChart configuration:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        alignTicks: true,
        animation: true,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        events: {
            load: function (e) {
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1398859200000, 1414753200000);
            }
        },
        ignoreHiddenSeries: true,
        renderTo: $('#chart')[0]
    },
    colors: [
        '#89f1a4',
        '#68d9f7',
        '#9eb9ef',
        '#c49eef'
    ],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0,
        enabled: true,
        navigation: {
            animation: true
        },
        shadow: false,
        verticalAlign: 'top'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: false,
        shared: true
    },
    navigator: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 10,
        maskFill: 'rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.7)',
        outlineWidth: 0,
        series: {
            type: 'column',
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [[
                    'week',
                    [1]
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInLegend: true,
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [[
                    'week',
                    [1]
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        max: 24,
        min: 0,
        ordinal: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%b %Y',
            month: '%b %Y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#ccc'
            }
        },
        minRange: 604800000,
        ordinal: false
    },
    series: data
});
```

**My question:**
How do I get the Navigator to reflect the complete data from the main chart?

Comment: It's not supported.  See here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series, your best bet will be to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068435/highstock-navigator-from-a-stacked-area-chart-shows-wrong-series

Comment: Brilliant - shouldda thought of that.  Thanks - post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2016, this is [still unsupported](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series) functionality.